# How to link other .o, .so, .a files to current cuda compliation

Tags: c++, c, linux, cuda, centos

I want to link libcudart.so to my cuda code such that reference to these functions should be available. when i fire readelf -Ws on .so file or .o file it shows multiple UND (Undefined) Entries. please help.

```
nvcc -c cuda/spmv/dispatch-float-float.cu -o cuda/spmv/dispatch-float-float.o -O2 -v -I. -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -DCUDA_ARCH=30 --ptxas-options -v --cudafe-options --diag_suppress=code_is_unreachable --compiler-options -fPIC --compiler-options -fpermissive
```

this is my compilation code. which does not link CUDA functions from libcudart.so file and CUDA functions remain undefined.

---

This is my Makefile, Please suggest the changes.

```
NVCC = nvcc
CUDA_PATH = $(shell which $(NVCC) | sed s@/bin/nvcc@@)

CUDA_ARCH = 35

CUDA_INCLUDE := -I$(CUDA_PATH)/include/

CXXWARN := -Wall -Wno-sign-compare
CXXOPT  := -O2
CXXFLAGS := $(CXXOPT) -g $(CXXWARN) -fPIC -I. $(CUDA_INCLUDE)

NVCCFLAGS := -O2 -v -I. -gencode arch=compute_$(CUDA_ARCH),code=sm_$(CUDA_ARCH) \
    -DCUDA_ARCH=$(CUDA_ARCH) \
    --ptxas-options -v \
    --cudafe-options --diag_suppress=code_is_unreachable \
    --compiler-options -fPIC

LIB = libispm0-pic.a
all: $(LIB)

SPMV_OBJS  = cuda/spmv/dispatch-float-float.o cuda/spmv/dispatch-double-float.o cuda/spmv/dispatch-double-double.o
EXTRA_OBJS = util/cuda/sblas.o fastainv/fastainv.o util/cuda/initialize.o
OBJS = $(SPMV_OBJS) $(EXTRA_OBJS)

$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    ar cr $@ $^

cuda/spmv/dispatch-%.o: cuda/spmv/dispatch-%.cu
    $(NVCC) -c $< -o $@ $(NVCCFLAGS) --compiler-options -fpermissive
    objcopy --localize-hidden $@

util/cuda/%.o: util/cuda/%.cu
    $(NVCC) -c $< -o $@ $(NVCCFLAGS)

fastainv/fastainv.o: fastainv/fastainv.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $< -o $@ $(CXXFLAGS)

clean:
    -rm $(OBJS) $(LIB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you mean is that you want to statically link against -lcudart so that these references are always resolved by the OS loader.

In recent CUDA toolkits, nvcc accepts the flags

> --cudart{none|shared|static}              (-cudart)
>           shared/dynamic CUDA runtime library, or static CUDA runtime library.
>           Allowed values for this option:  'none','shared','static'.

so maybe you could try adding --cudart static into your make rule.

Comment: How to include in make rule. please help.